# Registry Keys for Sharepoint2007 to allow Custom OpenDocuments control

Tags: document-library, custom, registry, launch

I asked this on stack overflow, and they recommended I ask here instead.

I am trying to create a custom version of SharePoint's OpenDocuments control following an article [on the MSDN sharepoint blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2010/05/13/using-custom-opendocuments-control-to-open-custom-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx).  Trying to use what is in that article doesn't seem to work for setting the registry on my machine to allow my control to appear.  I want to be able to have the Edit Document menu appear just like with the AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments or SharePoint.OpenDocuments options, but I cant get sharepoint to recognize that the client has an acceptible program installed.  Any help about what registry keys need to be set would be appreciated.

I first tried following the article exactly, then I tried setting all the same Registry entries that Acrobat set, but to no avail.  The DLL is in the directory referenced by the Registry Keys.  What did I miss?

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Koz.OpenDocuments.1]
@="Koz.OpenDocuments"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Koz.OpenDocuments.1\CLSID]
@="{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}]
@="Koz.OpenDocuments"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="Koz.OpenDocuments"
"Assembly"="Koz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fcb03c2826a13954"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="Koz.OpenDocuments"
"Assembly"="Koz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fcb03c2826a13954"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}\ProgId]
@="Koz.OpenDocuments.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0BB18692-36A3-4324-B1B4-A353F0DFE648}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting in contact with the author of the website I mentioned, I managed to debug some more of the issue.  It turns out that I changed stuff and it ended up with a new PublicKeyToken.  Once I fixed that in the registry files, my changes worked correctly.

The article is a great starting point, and I have managed to create a very detailed process that happens and an interceptor between sharepoint and the AcrobatX openDocument control.